# Why python 3.7.8 is not available from anaconda channel?

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm new to python and anaconda.I'm sorry if I asked a silly question.

When I tried to use conda to create a new environment with a specified version of Python,I noticed that python 3.7.8 was not available from anaconda channel(linux, windows and macOS).
Just being curious that why this version is not available?
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4YsT.png)

Comment: _Just being curious that why this version is not available?_ The (boring) answer is that they haven't made the package for it yet. You can get it from the conda-forge channel, though. As an aside, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: Thanks! I will pay attention to the useless images problem.